# Php Date Function with complexity

Tags: php, date, datediff, dateadd

My question: if the date is on Monday then my timer should start from 8:30 am and should calculate the time difference from 8:30 till date assigned, in this case its 2017-06-02 14:20:00 for first one. So time difference should be 5 hours 50 min.

Second case, date created on 2017-06-02 09:50:00 and date assigned is: 2017-06-03 13:20:00. SO it should calculate from 9:50 till 9:00pm and again start from 8:30 till 13:20:00 (if next day lies on mon-sat. If next day is sun then timer should calculate from 11am till 1:20pm. and should give me duration in hours and minutes.

How would I do that? Its in Php & MySQL. I am not any frameworks or CMS systems. Its native php.

My Data:

```
Date Created: 2017-06-02 02:50:00
Date Assigned: 2017-06-02 14:20:00

Date Created: 2017-06-02 09:50:00
Date Assigned: 2017-06-03 13:20:00

Mon - Sat   =   8:30am - 9:00pm
Sunday      =   11am - 5pm
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are you asking here specifically? are you having problems with the time difference? or you want to know how to achieve the logic thru PHP ?

Comment: Want to know how to achieve the logic through php

Comment: Organised your question you should as a question first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: This function checks first what day is your dateassigned, then calculates the time difference based on your criteria.

```
<?php 

    echo getTimeLapsedCustom('2017-06-02 14:20:00') . "<br>";
    echo getTimeLapsedCustom('2017-06-03 13:20:00') . "<br>";

    function getTimeLapsedCustom($time){
        $timecreated = '';
        $timeassigned = $time;
        $datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timeassigned);

        if($datetime2->format('D') === 'Sun'){
            $timecreated = $datetime2->format('Y-m-d') . ' 11:00:00';
        }else{
            $timecreated = $datetime2->format('Y-m-d') . ' 08:30:00';
        }


        $datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timecreated);

        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        return $interval->format('%h hours %i min');
    }
```

Results:

```
5 hours 50 min
4 hours 50 min
```

Comment: But need to calculate time only from || Mon - Sat = 8:30am - 9:00pm & for Sunday = 11am - 5pm only. before or after that, I dont want to consider that time. I am aware of datediff() but I am not getting the logic to exclude those times

Comment: then define which time you wanted to calculate from.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: So if Mon-Sat , you want to calculate the time difference from 8:30 am to the `dateassigned` , and 11am for Sun , correct?

Comment: Yes. thats Correct.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with `datecreated` , correct?

Comment: It has to do with datecreated. For example. datecreate is midnight and I assigned it in the afternoon but I want to just calculate timer from 8:30 till assigned date and time. if my datecreated is 10:00am and assigned at 1:00pm then timer will show only 3 hours. but if its 1:00am and assigned at 4:00pm then calculate from 8:30 till 4:00pm

Comment: EDITED, pls check.

Comment: perfect. thank you so much. relived my headache right now.

Comment: Pls. accept the answer if everythings okay on ur end.

Comment: One last ques: if the assigneddate is after one or two days then this would work or not?

Comment: please help me with this issue

Comment: CID,first_name,Created,D_Assigned
246,Michael,2017-06-01 1:20,2017-06-02 17:20
254,RÃ©mi,2017-06-01 4:26,2017-06-03 17:20
255,Anugakuluk,2017-06-01 4:57,2017-06-04 17:20
256,Reshmi,2017-06-01 5:00,2017-06-05 17:20
257,Leona,2017-06-01 5:36,2017-06-06 17:20
258,David,2017-06-01 5:52,2017-06-07 17:20
259,Arnold,2017-06-01 6:21,2017-06-08 17:20
260,Lans,2017-06-01 8:16,2017-06-09 17:20
261,Randy,2017-06-01 8:36,2017-06-10 17:20
262,Lemuel,2017-06-01 9:07,2017-06-11 17:20
263,Deepu,2017-06-01 10:48,2017-06-12 17:20
264,Leonard,2017-06-01 11:57,2017-06-01 4:01